# How to implement next/back function when using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website which shows a list of transaction records(10 records per page).

The page has **paging** and **searching** function, which allows user to view specific transaction record.(like date range, types....more than 10 parameters at most)

When user clicks anything(changing page/search criteria), a ajax call is used to fetch and display the transactions without reloading.

However, say, a user click next page(ajax call) to view page2 and trying to click the browser back button. The site will redirect him to another webpage instead of going back to page1.

I know that there is a `window.history.pushState` to change url without reloading in html5 at chrome/Firefox. But I have **to support older browsers** like IE7+/FF/Chrome/Safari.

Are there any existing solution to solve this problem? Thanks.

---

**Edit**:
I have tried the history.js this noon.

// newUrl: "?para1=value1&para2=value2&....

```
history.pushState({data:"searchTransaction"}, document.title, newUrl);
```

And the url has changed after the ajax request. And I have a problem is how to handle the change event. I want to bind the back/next(user click) event and get the "newUrl", then parse it back to a parameter map and do the ajax request again.
And I want to store the whole parameter array when pushState if possible.

Comment: Try `https://github.com/balupton/History.js/` ?

Comment: @kayen - Beat me to it :) I have used this successfuly in many projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you can't catch the 'back/next' event because it doesn't exists, but you can catch the *statechange*

```
// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

What I usually do is to catch the user's clicks, and if a statechange is trggered without a click I supose that the user does next or back.